Artifactory OSS error: Checksum input stream calculator does not support mark
I am attempting to setup artifactory in ECS using a dockerfile.
Version: Open source license 7.9.2 rev 70902900 undefined
I have it up and running, I created a generic repo through the ui.
As a test I want to upload a file via the UI to this generic test repo although when I do this I get this error:
Checksum input stream calculator does not support mark!
When testing on another older version of artifactory I don't get this issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated.



I used an older version of artifactory and did not get this issue.
